Need to send azure devops widget dashboard in MS teams
I have a azure widget dashboard about the status of the Work items, tasks etc. I need to send it to my teams standup group about the snapshot of the dashboard. How to do it.

Based on your description, you need to show the Azure DevOps widget dashboard in MS teams.
I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly show this dashboard in Teams Group chat.
I suggest that you can use the Azure DevOps app in MS Teams Teams Channel.
This app allows you to display the contents of the Azure DevOps dashboard directly in the teams channel
Here are the steps:
Step1: Install Azure DevOps app in Teams Channel.
Step2: Sign in your account and select the target organization.
Step3: You can select the target project and the team dashboard.

Step4: It will show the Azure DevOps Dashboard in Teams channel tab.
For example:

